# How can I install ClockworkMod recovery on my Motorola Defy+?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, motorola-defy

I want to install ClockworkMod recovery on my Motorola Defy+ in order to install Android 4.0.3 (ICS). Where can I get CMW to install? Are there any problems with ICS on the Defy Plus?

Answer (score 1):

Luckily rooting the Motorola Defy is pretty simple and doesn't require any extraneous measures. Please see [this link](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-root-motorola-defy-and-install-a-custom-recovery-video-guide/) for a tutorial on how to root and install a custom recovery (ie. clockworkmod) on your Motorola Defy.

As far as installing an ICS ROM, after doing some research it appears there is not a fully functional ROM available yet. However, if you are willing to give up a feature or two, you may be able to get a stable release running on your phone. Please refer to the [xda wiki page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Motorola_Defy/ICS_status) specifically for the ICS development status on the Motorola Defy for more information about the project.